# Normalizing a histogram data

Tags: histograms

I made a histogram of 1000 random coin tosses.How can I normalize the numbers in order to get the probabilities for each number. Basically, scaling the Y axis by a factor of 1/1000

The data are in the Table format.

Comment: Maybe this just is a bit of semantics but you get the proportions of the observed two numbers (usually 0 and 1) rather than the probabilities.  And if there are just two numbers, why would you want to create a histogram when reporting just two 2 numbers (1,000 and the proportion of observed heads) will tell as much about the results in a lot less space?

Comment: Does `Histogram[data,Automatic,"Probability"]` do what you want?

Answer (score 5):

As a summary, here are the different possibilities available to you.

## The Easy Way

As often in Mathematica, the easiest way is usually to use a built-in construct. As @Lukas mentioned in the comments, you can use the special height specification `"Probability"` in `Histogram[]` to get what you want.

```
data=Table[RandomInteger[],{1000}]
Histogram[data,Automatic,"Probability"]
```

[image]

## The Alternative

But maybe, as @Jim Baldwin said, an alternative visualisation is best? Sometimes, you can't beat a simple table...

```
counts = Tally@Table[RandomInteger[], {1000}];
Grid[{Text /@ {"", "heads", "tails"}, 
  Text /@ {"count", counts[[1, 2]], counts[[2, 2]]}, 
  Text /@ {"probability", N[counts[[1, 2]]/1000], 
    N[counts[[2, 2]]/1000]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

## The Straight Answer

Strictly speaking however, you are asking to normalize the histogram scale. To do this, you need to define a custom height function as defined in the "Details and Options" section of the [reference on `Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html).

```
heightfunction[bins_, counts_] := counts/1000;
Histogram[Table[RandomInteger[], {1000}], {{0, 0.5, 1.1}}, heightfunction]
```

[image]

Note: I also adjusted the bins to remove the empty space on the left